# Can't see even own computer in the Network view of File Explorer in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares

### Preface

One of my laptop is hooked up to the internet via ethernet cable. However, network sharing doesn't seem to work for it. When I go to the Network section of File Explorer, normally I should see at least the laptop's own computer name there but I see none. It just says "This folder is empty."

[image]

### What I've tried

- Made the ethernet connection a private network
- Made sure in Network and Sharing Center that "Turn on network discovery" and "Turn on file and printer sharing" is selected
- Made sure that the "Function Discovery Provider Host" service is running (I even turned it off and on again just for good measure)

### Extra things to note

I noticed that in other computers, there is a "(current profile)" text next to the active profile as seen below.

[image]

However, on this laptop, even though the network is set to Private already and control panel confirms this, none of the three options have "(current profile)" beside them.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is related or anything but I figured I should mention it anyway to maybe help narrow down the problem.

In the above screenshots, both devices are using absolutely the exact same Windows version and build.

Comment: Is this a network issue or a protocol issue? Can you ping `localhost` or another device on the LAN/internet? What subversion of Windows 10 are you using? Did you install all the updates? Did you check if the appropriate services for network discovery are running?

Comment: Go to "Network and Sharing Centre" (not in the advanced settings) - under "View your active Networks" it should tell you what the network type is there

Comment: @Albin yes, I can ping localhost. As for your question if it's a network issue or a protocol issue, I have no idea. Since I can't see other computers on the network I'm assuming it's a network issue?

Comment: @JaromandaX It says "Private network".

Comment: OK then, I don't see "current profile" in my windows 10 either, so either Microsoft has changed that, or that image is not from windows 10 :p

Comment: @user9564371 Can you ping another device on the LAN/internet? What subversion of Windows 10 are you using? Did you install all the updates? Did you check if the appropriate services for network discovery are running? Please add the information to your question as well.